# UbuntuUI Html5 api optionselector - how to get and set selected Index?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, html5

I'm trying to use the optionselector in an **html5**-app.
But it seems impossible to get the selected option (index or whatever). I also want to set the index as predefined choice.

Here is my html:

```
<div class="settingGroup">
  <p>Video Transcoding:</p>
  <section data-role="option-selector" id="transcodingOptions">
    <ul>
      <li data-value="0">
        <p>no transcoding</p>
      </li>
      <li data-value="1">
        <p>simple transcoding</p>
      </li>
      <li data-value="2">
        <p>full transcoding</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</div>
```

and JS:

```
UI.optionselector("transcodingOptions", false);
// always the same index:
console.debug(UI.optionselector("transcodingOptions").selectedIndex);

// seems to get the right data-value (fires three times):
UI.optionselector("transcodingOptions").onClicked(function(e) {
  console.debug(e.values);
  // save:
  localStorage.setItem("transcoding", e.values);
});

// set selectedIndex --> not working:
UI.optionselector("transcodingOptions").selectedIndex = localStorage.getItem("transcoding");
```

Does anybody know the right way to, what I'm trying to achieve?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a generic programming question .. you should ask it on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: hm, the optionselector is an Ubuntu api module and my intention was, to get an info how to use the module the right way, with its own methods and properties. 
Perhaps it is buggy and some Ubuntu api developer pays attention on it.
I know that I could parse the html elements if it has the class "active" or something similar. --> this would be an answer that I would exspect on normal stackoverflow.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not about Ubuntu and therefore off topic since programming questions are far of the scope we cant provide support for that, so you might be better off asking your question on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com). Please do not cross-post, flag your answer instead for moderator attention if you wish it to be migrated there. Thank you.

Comment: @Videonauth Per the faq "Development on Ubuntu" is on-topic.  This is also Ubuntu-centric devolopment (Ubuntu API).   I can't see how this is off-topic.  (Which isn't to say that SO might not generate more or better answers.)